# Swapping of 30 Movie Clips which are on stage and can be removed randomly but must be swapped properly?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe, swap

I got 30 movie clips like delivery , delivery1 ....delivery29.

Each delivery box contains an item text field , table text field and a quantity text field I have 77 different items button on  the stage . Whenever a button is clicked  that item name goes to the delivery movie clip's item text box .

When a movie clip delivery... delivery 29 is clicked that clip will be removed and then the `x` and `y` position of delivery must be swapped with the movie clip below it.

Each Movie clip's height is 16.00 there is a gap of 3 pixels in each movie clip for hit test so that the movie clips must not be over lapped.

How to swap the movie clips in a proper way like there are 10 movie clips named from 1 to 10 .If 3 is removed then `3.y` will be stored in `4.y` , `4.y` will be stored in `5.y` .... `9.y` will be stored in `10.y`. Then any movie clip from 1 to 10 can be added at any where in 1 to 10 .

Please guys give help me code these.

Comment: How are they added to the stage?  FlashPro timeline? through code?

Comment: Movie clips are on timeline . They are only visible when a label is stored in the item text box.

Comment: Too many questions arise from this text. What if there's no "movie clip below" the one that's clicked? How do you determine that "below" MC? What are those 10 MCs you try to shift upwards when one is clicked? What are those 30 "Delivery" MCs related to these 10? What's with 77 buttons? I say split your task into several that are more manageable first, say organize those delivery MCs into an interactive object with logic to manipulate them, then describe what commands it should receive and how it should act based on them, etc etc etc.

Comment: hello @Vesper , actually those 10 movie clip is just an idea how those 30 delivery movieclips must be. I just want a swapping function where the movie clip which is click will be removed and all other below that movie clip  will go up .That means any movie clip from 30 delivery movie clip can be clicked and all below will go a up .

Comment: So you want to have a column of MCs, then if one is clicked, others in that column should shift upwards to occupy its space and not lose their order? Yes it's doable. You create a container, make an `Array` out of them MCs in that container, then if a MC is about to be removed, you `splice()` it out of that array and reassign the remaining MC's `y` property so that they will be at places according to their index in the array: `mcs[i].y=19*i;` where 19 s your height (16) plus gap (3).